# MediaPlayer перестает работать в ViewPager при пролистывании

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

В фрагментах использую MediaPlayer для воспроизведения коротких аудио отрывков в формате .mp3, у меня 10 фрагментов, использую ViewPager для пролистывания, после 7-го фрагмента Medaplayer перестает воспроизводить аудио, кликаешь на кнопку и ничего не происходит. Ошибок ни каких не выдает, после закрытия и открытия снова начинает работать. В чем может быть проблема и как её решить?

Для воспроизведения использую код ниже:

```
final MediaPlayer voice = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.raw.sound_1);
        Button play = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonReplay);

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                voice.start();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что в каждом новом фрагменте создаёте новый экземпляр плеера, а он обращается к общей для всех приложений системной службе, коя и начинает сбоить при слишком большом кол-ве запросов к ней. Чтобы решить эту проблему и освободить ресурсы плеера после его использования,  необходимо вызвать метод `OnCompletionListener` и в нем вызывать функцию `release()`. Делать это можно по событию окончания проигрывания к-л файла.

```
play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MediaPlayer voice = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.raw.sound_1);
        voice.start();
        voice.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer voice) {
                voice.release();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: @Nikolai, при листании фрагментов пейджере они уничтожаются. Покажите как вы в коде обрабатываете этот момент. Имеется в иду - что у вас при этом с плеером происходит? Его надо остановить по крайней мере.

Comment: @Nikolai, я точно не помню как, и погуглить сейчас нет времени. Попробуйте `release` на плеере в `onStop` фрагмента вызывать. Возможно при этом понадобится переинициализация плеера в следующих фрагментах.

Comment: @Nikolai, я добавил это в ответ. Пожалуйста, отметьте его "верным" и/или дополните через редактирование.

Comment: сделано! Я поправил описание и код.